# creating the offline maps and routing

Tags: iphone, maps

I am creating the app for the offline maps in iphone . I want to select the two plces and draw the route among the selected places .   I found this link

http://www.gisnotes.com/wordpress/category/sqlite3/. When i am following the steps , i didnt found  this map2sqlite-1.0.tar.bz2.even though i got it from other . but the database is not created , in the  second step . in the above link . I found the route me third party api, but i am not understanding how to use it . Can anyone sugget me how to create the offline maps

Answer (score 0):

It is now on Github [map2sqlite](https://github.com/magiconair/map2sqlite).